# Fontspec: Font not found - Mobile XeTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, android, verbtex

This is yet another question of this kind, altough, to my defense, not answers of similar questions helped me solve my problem yet.

I'm having trouble loading some fonts in XeTeX, using an app called ‘VerbTeX’.

The I want to use are called `Courier Prime Bold.ttf`, etc. and are located in a folder called `HUe`.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
letterpaper,%
ngerman,%
]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
Path=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/verbosus.verbtex/files/Remote/HUe/,
Extension=.ttf,
BoldFont=* Bold,
ItalicFont=* Italic,
BoldItalicFont=* Bold Italic,
] 
{Courier Prime}

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

---

Android  10
VerbTeX 4.2.8

Comment: Just guessing: does the app have the permission to read from remote storage?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I just checked, yes it should have access to storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VerbTeX needs to upload external files (images, data files, font files etc.) to the server to allow for processing. To know which files need to be uploaded they need to be added explicitly as a 'resource' to your VerbTeX project.

To do this, you need to go to the Projects list, then long tap you project, then go to *Manage Files*, then press ADD to find the font file on your device and add to to the project. Next time you compile these files will be sent to the server that compiles the code so they are available for the compilation process.

Note that I tested this only in Local Mode, I'm not sure it works completely the same in Cloud Mode but it is probably similar.

Two screenshots for reference:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned, that I use Cloud Mode, where the file limit doesn't exist. However!— I have added the files in Local, then copied to Cloud, and it works now. Thank you very much!